# I want to ecrypt my password and also want to know how to insert the date of birth or optional data in php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to add the date of birth and gender and location options in this code and this code also have some bugs and also want to encrypt my password any body help

```
 <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "mydb";


// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
if(isset($_POST['register-user']))
{
$name = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$date_of_birth = $_POST['$year'.'$day'.'$month'];

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO 
mydata(name,email,Password,Gender,Country,Language) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $name, 
$email,$date_of_birth,$gender);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
?>
```

Comment: Update your database table structure and html

Comment: The number of placeholders don't match

Comment: can you guide me where is a mistake?

Comment: @LuckyBoy You try to fill a new row with 6 columns, but your `VALUES` part has only 3 values.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change

```
$date_of_birth = $_POST['$year'.'$day'.'$month'];
```

To

```
$date_of_birth = $_POST['year']."-". $_POST['month']."-".$_POST['day'];
```

Use password_hash for password encryption

```
$encryptedPassword=password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Comment: Don't use `md5()` for password hashing, use `password_hash()` instead.